# how can we bind filtered json data after slider event to redraw widget function in highcharts..?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, grep

I'm using json data for my chart in high charts. Here i'm also using a range slider with the y axis value. I used grep function to filter json data supplied to chart, i got slider end regions value . and i applied it in grep to filter my json data to redraw the chart when slider range varies dyanmically. Here i want to use jquery widget binding conecpt to bind my filtered json data for new chart to draw. How can i achieve that..?? any idea.. i got stuck there. please help me. And there was a possibility that if a user want to change chart type.. how can i achieve that also...please help me friends.. how can i use jquery widget binding conecpt to bind my filtered json data for new chart to draw

my code is

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
        <script src="http://blacklabel.github.io/grouped_categories/grouped-categories.js "></script>
        <div class="chart-container" id="chart-more"></div>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="../Chart_with _slider/slider.css">
        <script src="../Chart_with _slider/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="../Chart_with _slider/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        var Report;
            Test();
        });
        function Test()
        {
            Highcharts.setOptions({
                chart: {
                    borderWidth: 5,
                    borderColor: '#e8eaeb',
                    borderRadius: 0,
                    backgroundColor: '#f7f7f7'
                },
                title: {
                    style: {
                        'fontSize': '1em'
                    },
                    useHTML: true,
                    x: -27,
                    y: 8,
                    text: 'Report'
                }
            });

            Report = [
{
    "Name": "Sam",
    "Month": "January",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 20,
    "Leave": 1
}, {
    "Name": "Sam",
    "Month": "February",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 20,
    "Leave": 1
},
{
    "Name": "Sam",
    "Month": "March",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 15,
    "Leave": 6
},
{
    "Name": "Sam",
    "Month": "April",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 19,
    "Leave": 2
},
{
    "Name": "Sam",
    "Month": "May",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 20,
    "Leave": 1
},
{
    "Name": "David",
    "Month": "January",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 21,
    "Leave": 0
},
{
    "Name": "David",
    "Month": "February",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 20,
    "Leave": 1
},
{
    "Name": "David",
    "Month": "March",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 19,
    "Leave": 2
},
{
    "Name": "David",
    "Month": "April",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 21,
    "Leave": 0
},
{
    "Name": "David",
    "Month": "May",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 21,
    "Leave": 0
},
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Month": "January",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 16,
    "Leave": 5
},
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Month": "February",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 12,
    "Leave": 9
},
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Month": "March",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 20,
    "Leave": 1
},
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Month": "April",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 15,
    "Leave": 6
},
{
    "Name": "John",
    "Month": "May",
    "WorkingDays": 21,
    "Attendance": 21,
    "Leave": 0
}
];
            var newSeriesWorkingDays = {
                name: 'WorkingDays',
                data: []
            };
            var newSeriesAttendance = {
                name: 'Attendance',
                data: []
            };
            var newSeriesLeave = {
                name: 'Leave',
                data: []
            };
            var userNames = [];
            var userNameMonths = [];
            $.each(Report, function (index, User) {debugger;
                // get the series
                newSeriesWorkingDays.data.push(User.WorkingDays);
                newSeriesAttendance.data.push(User.Attendance);
                newSeriesLeave.data.push(User.Leave);
                // Get the usernames
                if (userNames[User.Name]) {
                    if (userNames[User.Name]['months']) {
                        userNames[User.Name]['months'][User.Month] = User.Month;
                    }
                } else {
                    userNames[User.Name] = {
                        'months': []
                    };
                    userNames[User.Name]['months'][User.Month] = User.Month;
                }
            });
            var newCategories = [];
                for (var name in userNames) {
                    if (userNames.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
                        var tempObj = {}
                        tempObj.name = name;
                        tempMonths = userNames[name]['months'].sort();
                        tempObj.categories = [];
                        for (var month in tempMonths) {
                            tempObj.categories.push({
                                name: month
                            });
                        }
                        newCategories.push(tempObj);
                    }
                }

            window.chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
                chart: {
                    renderTo: "chart-more",
                    type: "column"
                },
                series: [newSeriesWorkingDays, newSeriesAttendance, newSeriesLeave],
                xAxis: {
                    categories: newCategories
                }
            });
              }
$(function() {
    $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 30,
      values: [ 0, 30 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        var a = (  + ui.values[ 0 ]);
        var b = (  + ui.values[ 1 ]);
        //alert(a);
        //alert(b);
        //alert("The chart is being redrawn");
        var  flterData = filterDate(a, b);
        Test();
      }
    });
  });
        //slider change function
        function filterDate(a, b) {
            Report = jQuery.grep(Report, function(element, index){debugger;
            return element.WorkingDays > a && element.Attendance > a && element.Leave > a &&
                   element.WorkingDays < b && element.Attendance < b && element.Leave < b ;
             // retain appropriate elements
            });
        }
        </script>
        <div class="chart-container" id="chart-more"></div>
        <div id="slider-range"style="width:300px;border:1px solid red;">

            <br>
            <input type="text" id="startValue" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
            <input type="text" id="endValue" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f; font-weight:bold;">
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```